# Open a new window for a link on each click

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, window.open

I have an **asp.net** application that contains a link which opens a window on click.

**Example:**
<a href="url" onclick="window.open(url, name, parameters)">

This works fine. It opens a window as required. What I want is the application to open the window as many times as the link is clicked and in a separate window.

1st click opens the first window.
2nd click opens a second window of the same link.
3rd click opens a third window of the same link.

I want a maximum of 5 windows of the same link to be opened with one window per click. If possible, how would I achieve this?

Comment: Why from a usability standpoint would you want to do this? I can't see a case where users wouldn't be annoyed at this.

Comment: @Tim. It was a client requirement. They wanted to restrict the number of windows that could be opened at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

It's not hard. You must anyway keep track of the windows so you're able to update your counting when one of them is closed.

Easier way: poll their status (event-based tracking is a nightmare).

```
<script>
var openWindows = {};
var openWindow = function (url, name, specs) {
    var count = openWindows[name] || 0;
    if (count < 5) {
        var w = window.open(url, name + count, specs);
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            if(!w || w.closed){
                clearInterval(interval);
                openWindows[name] = openWindows[name] - 1;
                console.log('Closed a window for button ' + name);
            }
        }, 100);
        openWindows[name] = count + 1;
    }
    console.log('Opened a window for button ' + name);
};
</script>
<!-- Usage -->
<input id="btn" name="btn" type="button" onclick="openWindow('http://www.google.it', 'google', 'width=200,height=100');" />
```

The script basically stores the name you provide, changes it to make it unique (otherwise popups would overlap) and starts a timed poll, which checks every 100msec and is stopped when the window object is no longer there or the window is closed. I added some console spam to make it clearer.

**Important** The counting won't survive a page refresh. This is an issue that can only be safely taken care of server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Have a list with link and it's count. on every click try to find the link in the list, increase the count. if the link is not found in the list just add it in the list with a count of 1.

```
    <a href="url" onclick="openWindow(url, name, parameters)">

    <script>
    var countLinkPair = [];

    function openWindow(url, name, parameters)
    {
        var flag = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < countLinkPair.length; i++) {
            var obj = countLinkPair[i];
            if (obj.link == url) {
                if (obj.count<=5) {
                    window.open(url, name, parameters);
                }
                obj.count++;
                flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!flag) {
            countLinkPair.push({link:url, count:1});
        }
    }
    </script>
```